# Javascript function, changing values of variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I've got a little problem with javascript function.
Here's the situation :

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  var value = parseInt($('#my_id').text(), 10);
  if(value > 0) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    console.log(value);
  }
}, 600);
```

When I console.log the value in this part of the code, my value is right.
But If I try to console.log outside my function, I don't get the right value for my variable.

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  var value = parseInt($('#my_id').text(), 10);
  if(value > 0) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    return value;      
  }
}, 600);
console.log(intervalId); //Wrong value here, I want the same result as I got previously
```

Can anyone help me to get the same value outside my function please ?

Cordially, Rob.

Comment: `intervalId` is pointing to the `setInterval` handle, what value are you expecting?

Comment: The same value I got with console.log(value); in the first code part

Comment: You can't because it's scoped in the anonymous function. You can declare `value` globally but then you no longer have info about the interval events. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: you can't get the value because the function passed to setInterval is executed only at a later stage

Comment: Well I try to get the value of a tag (only integer in this tag) after 0.6 seconds. And I want to store this value inside a variable accesible everywhere I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean `console.log(value);` in the second part of the code, anyway your problem is that you are defining the variable inside a function and then it's scoped there, you cannot see it outside. So you can do like this:

```
var value;
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  value = parseInt($('#my_id').text(), 10);
  if(value > 0) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    console.log(value + ' inside function');
  }
}, 600);
console.log(value + ' outside function');
```

I don't know how the rest of your code looks like, but you can check this [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju6PV/) which reads the value outside in the begging (too early because you set it first after 600ms) and after 4 seconds.

P.s - I don't know what is your `#my_id`, bur doing `parseInt` on a elements `.text()` can give some bugs...

Comment: the second console.log returns me undefined

Comment: @user2462805 it does, because the code executes immediately, and the value is set after 600ms timeout

Comment: @user2462805, yes it does, just that you are looking for it too fast. Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ju6PV/

Answer (score 0):

setInterval doesn't return your value. Whatever you're returning inside the closure is passed to setInterval. setInteval passes the Interval which can be cleared using setInterval. Plus what you are doing is logically incorrect. setInteraval will not populate intervalId everytime it is called. IT returns immediately after setting the interval.

To get access to this value, call a function inside your closure

```
function doSomething(val){console.log(val)};
...
if(value > 0) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    doSomething(value);    
  }
```